# Removing File Extensions from URL

Tags: html, .htaccess

I can't seem to find an answer online despite trying my best.

I recently set up hosting with StackCP and I have a domain through GoDaddy.

I am trying to remove the .html extension from my links. I want site.com/terms to take you to site.com/terms.html. I've read quite a bit and so far I've tried this

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.html [NC, L]
```

I've placed this in my .htaccess file in the root with index.html and the terms.html any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep this  inside the **.htaccess** file for removing .html extension from the url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is this all I need? Because with just that in my .htaccess it doesn't seem to do anything. Do I need to change {REQUEST_FILENAME} to the name of the file?

Comment: Actually, it does appear to be working, almost, the issue appears to be that when it redirects to terms.html it's adding a tailing / and that is breaking the link.

Comment: Yes no need to do any thing just put the above code in your .htaccess and it will remove the .html extension from the url.

to remove trailing / form the url add the below line 
`RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]` at the end of the above code. Hope it will work.